# All children disabled, only one mouse active

Tags: actionscript-3, click, mouseevent, children

I have a Movieclip (instance: my_mc) that holds Sprite, Bitmap, Texfield and Button (children)

The Movieclip (my_mc) has some variables I want to access from my event through `e.target`

```
my_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, my_fc);
function my_fc(e:MouseEvent):void{
    ...
}
```

so when someone clicks on a object that is a child of my_mc, only my_mc actually receives the CLICK

for this purpose I used `my_mc.mouseChildren = false;`

BUT I also need to have button still active so that would be only child that also receives the CLICK when someone clicks it. I have tried to add `button.mouseEnabled = true;` but that doesn't work...

Any suggestions?

Comment: what about using mouseEnabled = false for all the other children but the button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cauko, skus toto....

This is assuming that your button is called btn, if there are more you might need to assign the 2ndary listener dynamically. You cannot use `my_mc.mouseChildren = false;` because that removes all mouse events.

```
my_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, my_fc);
function my_fc(e:MouseEvent):void{
    doSomething(e.target as MovieClip)
}
my_mc.btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, my_fc2);
function my_fc2(e:MouseEvent):void{
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    doSomething(e.target.parent);
}
function doSomething(mc:MovieClip):void{
    trace(mc);
}
```

Comment: I'm going to consider what you said: mouseChildren removes all children mouse events. I will make a workaround using object names and conditions. Thanks

Comment: this is just to show the potential with multiple listeners and propagation handling. without knowing what you're trying to do with it it's hard to say what the best way to go is. you might not need to stop the propagation at all, and you can access the parent mc's properties through `e.target.parent.my_val` as-well

Answer (score 2):

If the button is inside of my_mc then you need to use `my_mc.button.mouseEnabled = true;`

and be sure to have an event listener for my_mc.button aswell: `my_mc.button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, buttonHandler);`

and a buttonHandler function aswell.

And if it still doesn't work....

Separate the buttons into a different movieclip and position them to where you want them to be. Then just simply use  `my_mc.mouseChildren = false;` on your original movieclip and not on the buttons.